# Django queryset ManytoMany and OnetoMany

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this models.py

```
class Sitename(models.Model): 
   #id              = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  ## to be removed
    site            = models.CharField()                  ## find values

class Equipment(models.Model):
   #id              = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  ## to be removed
    serialno        = models.CharField()                  ## known values

class RSL(models.Model): ##Radio Station License
   #id              = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  ## to be removed
    sitename        = models.ForeignKey(Sitename)
    equipment       = models.ManyToManyField(Equipment)
```

I only know the `Equipment` `serialno`, I can't figure out the proper queryset?
So far I know how to query a foreignkey.

```
sn       = 'abc'

equip    = Equipment.objects.get(serialno=sn)
rsl      = RSL.objects.?????
sitename = Site.objects.get(pk=rsl.pk)
```

Comment: `RSL.objects.get(pk=1)`?

Comment: "So far I know how to query a foreignkey." - perhaps you should go through the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: I'm bad, I did not know how to use the `_set` until now.

Comment: Django auto generates the ID field. You do not need to explicitly define it, unless you really need it. Keep your model definitions compact and neat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the equipment serial no., so use -

```
equip = Equipment.objects.get(serialno=sn)
```

Because your `equipment` field of RSL class and `Equipment` class are a Many2Many relation, there maybe more than one RSL class objects related to one Equipment object. To get the queryset, use -

```
rsl_queryset = equip.rsl_set.all()
```

(Please check whether `rsl_set` is a method of equip object by checking if it is listed in `dir(equip)`. Looking at your model, most probably it is. BTW, you can change it to the name you want by adding related_name = "name you want" to the definition.
For eg: -

`equipment = models.ManyToManyField(Equipment, related_name = "rsl_objects")`

This way you can access it by `rsl_queryset = equip.rsl_objects.all()`)

Now you have got a queryset containing RSL objects related to equip object. So, iterate over them to get the values you want -

```
for rsl_object in rsl_queryset:
    print "site = " + rsl_object.sitename.site
```

Comment: That is well explained..Adding a for loop aside from using `_set`.